# Is there a possibility to perform non-case sensitive "where" request to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a request to Firestore to check if the collection of tickets contains some duplicated IDs:

```
firestore.collection("tickets").where("extId", "==", "Test 2").get();
```

The problem is - `where` method looks up only for case-sensitive IDs.

Is there a chance I can return a document with `test 2` or `tesT 2` extId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Firestore queries are case sensitive and there is no way to avoid this. Here are some approaches you could take to solve this problem depending on your use case:

**1.** Store several versions of your data (eg store both an upper and lower case version of your data)

**2.** Don't allow users to type in their query, and instead provide them with predefined filter items (for example chips, or a dropdown menu)

**3.** Do some client side processing before executing the query (eg. convert query strings into upper or lowercase to ensure it matches the format in the document)

**4.** Use a search engine platform on top of Firestore such as Algolia, Typesense, Meilisearch, among others as they contain typo-tolerance and other additional features

Answer (score 0):

As also @Hydra mentioned in her answer, the queries in Firestore are case-sensitive, meaning that will always return documents with the exact match. If you want to get documents with `test 2` **OR** `tesT 2`, then you should consider using [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any):

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical **OR**. An `in` query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.

In your particular case, the following query will do the trick:

```
firestore.collection("tickets").where("extId", "in", ["test 2", "tesT 2"]).get();
```